# extracting specific function calls from javascript

Tags: javascript, esprima, acorn

I want to extract function calls from javascript files.

For example:

```
...........
...........
...........
function moveEvent(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay){
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: 'id=' + event.id + '&title=' + event.title + '&day_delta=' + dayDelta + '&minute_delta=' + minuteDelta + '&all_day=' + allDay,
        dataType: 'script',
        type: 'post',
        url: "/events/move"
    });
}
...........
...........
...........
```

I want to extract the complete calls:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        data: 'id=' + event.id + '&title=' + event.title + '&day_delta=' + dayDelta + '&minute_delta=' + minuteDelta + '&all_day=' + allDay,
        dataType: 'script',
        type: 'post',
        url: "/events/move"
    })
```

I presume I have to use some JS tokenizer like Esprima for this. Any code sample pointers is welcome.